# Aligning hexagons navigation

Tags: css, css-float

I've struggling to position these hexagons next to each other on 3 lines, here is the page I'm trying to manipulate http://goo.gl/xpHmw

effect I'm trying to achieve

http://www.queness.com/resources/images/13901.gif

Many thanks for any help and assistance.

Comment: Your website is not work friendly. It's restricted by a firewall.

Comment: dang not sure why this is, other people can view it strange I'll try and fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably many ways of achieving it. My solution would probably be wrapping the hexagons in a relatively positioned container, assign a `position: absolute` to all the hexagons and position each of them manually with 'left' and 'top'.

I've abstracted the code for you to better understand. 
http://codepen.io/nobitagit/pen/ojvue

ps - next time you ask a question you'd better abstract your problem in jsfiddle.net or codepen so other people will likely find it easier to answer you and the problem + solution will be there for others to see in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember this tip for next time

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I just checked your website at home.

This isn't something that's very easy to do in CSS because it doesn't fit very well into rectangles or "blocks" like CSS employs.

I have some suggestions. Perhaps it doesn't "answer" your question but it will give you a good start.

Div tags do not hold semantic value and they are "empty" in that regard. In this case, you used numerous div tags inside an unordered list `<ul>` to create backgrounds for the hexagons. This is fine and all but I would recommend:

- Remove the divs completely. An unordered list really shouldn't have divs. It is an "unordered" list afterall. I would either use divs exclusively or better yet:
- Use an unordered list and create each hexagon as a background. One box holds -> 1 hexagon. The hexagons do not scale. No reason to have a separate div for the top/bottom.

You don't have to use absolute positioning. You simply need to have some of these hexagons overlap. For the second row of hexagons you can use a negative margins to offset and place them in the correct location. Use .png for transparenencies on the corners!

Pseudo solution:

- Each hexagon takes up a square.
- Create hexagon backgrounds as .png in photoshop
- Hold each in a `<li>` and float them in a `<ul>` --> do not use divs
- Use a negative top margin to overlap the second row into the cracks of the other hexagons.

Good luck. Post an update with your progress. I'll help you further; but I can't produce a solution for you.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'm just trying to make it as responsive as possible and regarding the ul's I'll try and figure out a more standardised way.